# Remove items from discovery database

Tags: web8, discovery-service

According to the product documentation, "One shortcoming of the [Discovery Registration] Tool is that it cannot delete registered Capabilities."

I accidentally created incorrect capabilities. Can I go into the SQL Server Studio and delete rows from the CONFIGURATION_ITEM and CONFIGURATION_ITEM_LINKS tables? Or will this corrupt my database?

Comment: Maybe it is better to run registration tool update with proper new capabilities?

Comment: I could do that, but unfortunately I have accidentally added a capability (session preview) that shouldn't exist at all for this environment (because it's live)

Comment: Then probably the only way to do it on Web 8 is indeed hacking the database. In Web 8 patch release (which will be released on March 31st) abilities of discovery registration tool will be extended.

How about to re-create discovery database from zero?

Comment: As Stanislav states, you'd need to remove the entries from the discovery database. Please ensure the CD services are stopped when you do this.

Comment: How do I know which entries to remove? Can I simply remove all records from the tables mentioned above and start from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Discovery Registration Tool as follow:

java -jar discovery-registration.jar sync

sync option deletes unused (not included or comented in cd_storage_conf.xml) capabilities.

good luck!